# Finding a route between two points across different routes

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that represent as points of origin

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        route: 1,
        point: 'A'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        route: 1,
        point: 'B',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        route: 2,
        point: 'B'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        route: 2,
        point: 'C'
    }
];
```

My objective is to find if there is a route possible across to two different points (in this case '1' and '2'), where two points have to be different and two points can be connected by a different point.

So for example

> A --> C

is possible because A is on route "1" and C is on route "2". Also because for `route: 1` its A --> B and for `route:2` its B --> C, so hence A --> C

> B --> C

is not possible because B is on route "1" and "2" so you will be hitting B twice

At the moment I am not sure what would be the logic to achieve this and appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching routes of length equal to 3, this might be a simple (but not very efficient) algorithm:

Given the start point `S` and end point `E` and your list `L` of point-route-data.

1. For each entry in `L` with `point == S` add its `route` to a collection `R_S`
2. For each entry in `L` with `point == E` add its `route` to a collection `R_E`
3. For each entry in `L` check whether the `point` is neither `S` nor `E` and whether its `route` is contained in `R_S` and `R_E`, if this is the case return the current element
4. If no hit was found in 3. return null